# What does a sideways "s" over a note mean?

Tags: notation, keyboard

For example, from Bach's two part invention no. 11 (G minor):

[image: Example of musical score containing this symbol]

Comment: [A little research goes a long way.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_musical_symbols#Ornaments)

Comment: Google search is wonderful ... but only if you know what to type into the search box. (Not sure that "sideways 's'" gets good results!)

Comment: @OldJohn - 'music signs symbols' works well.

Comment: @Tim And now thanks to this question it works for "sideways s" too. This site is part of that knowledge database you guys are suggesting to use, don't forget that.

Comment: Thank you for posting this question.  It helped me find exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That would be a "turn" - a common ornament in the baroque period.

You can find a (fairly basic) explanation [here on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornament_%28music%29#Turn),

and there are more detailed explanations in many books and articles on Baroque ornamentation.

You can also see Bach's own explanation [here on the Dolmetsch website](http://www.dolmetsch.com/musictheory23.htm).

Here is Bach's own explanation, from the Dolmetsch website, showing symbols for different ornamentation figures that were used in this style period, with an example of how each might be played. The "turn" is number 4 on this chart.

[image]

Comment: What your graph gives as a regular mordant is in fact an inverted mordant. A regular mordant does not have the line through it. It also goes up where the inverted mordant goes down.

Comment: @NeilMeyer, that is, in fact, the only kind of mordent there was in the Baroque. Upper mordents didn't exist. The sign you call a mordent is used for a trill starting on the upper auxiliary. That's _Bach's_ table of ornaments, by the way, directly from his Klavierbüchlein für Wilhelm Friedemann. You won't really find upper mordents until roughly Carl Czerny's time.

Comment: That being Bach's table, you are going to play the turn in a similar fashion to what is marked as "cadence" above, starting from the upper auxiliary.

Comment: Note: This is true for J.S. Bach and contemporaries, but for most later composers, these ornaments are executed differently.  In particular, the turn is generally 5 notes, with the principal note played first.  Also, you often see the ornament not directly over the note, but over the empty space after it, which means that principal note should be held for a while before the turn.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman, true - again roughly around Czerny's generation. Baroque (and High Classical) notions of ornaments involving the upper auxiliary tended to see them as a form of appoggiatura. There seems to have been a shift over time from seeing ornaments as a kind of _dissonance_ to seeing them as _decoration_. The delayed turn, though, was current all through the periods under discussion.